# Spring Jax-ws service with JBOSS 5.1.0 giving Introspection Exception

Tags: web-services, spring, jboss5.x

Hi I am developing a Spring -Jaxws web service using JBOSS 5. I am using "SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter" to deploy the service. My service endpoint is :

package com.pb.pts.spring.service;

```
@Component
@WebService(serviceName="ParcelTrackingService")
public class ParcelTrackingServiceEndpoint {

@Autowired
public ParcelTrackingService trackingService;

@WebMethod
public String createParcelDetails(ParcelDetails details) throws TrackingException{
return trackingService.createParcelDetails(details);
}

@WebMethod
public ParcelTrackingData getParcelTrackingDetails(ParcelTrackingRequestData requestData) throws TrackingException{
return trackingService.getParcelTrackingDetails(requestDa ta);
}

}

The TrackingException class is :

public class TrackingException extends Exception {
private TrackingError[] errors;

public TrackingException() {
super();
this.errors = null;
}

public TrackingError[] getErrors() {
return errors;
}

public void setErrors(TrackingError[] errors) {
this.errors = errors;
}

}
```

I get the following error while deploying on jboss :

```
org.jboss.ws.WSException: Property 'errors' not found in fault bean 'com.pb.pts.spring.service.jaxws.TrackingException Bean'
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.FaultMetaData.initializ eFaultBean(FaultMetaData.java:282)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.FaultMetaData.eagerInit ialize(FaultMetaData.java:225)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.OperationMetaData.eager Initialize(OperationMetaData.java:468)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.eagerI nitializeOperations(EndpointMetaData.java:559)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.initia lizeInternal(EndpointMetaData.java:543)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData.eagerI nitialize(EndpointMetaData.java:533)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.ServiceMetaData.eagerIn itialize(ServiceMetaData.java:433)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.UnifiedMetaData.eagerIn itialize(UnifiedMetaData.java:194)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EagerInitializeDeployment Aspect.start(EagerInitializeDeploymentAspect.java: 48)
at org.jboss.wsf.framework.deployment.DeploymentAspec tManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentAspectManagerImpl.ja va:129)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.ArchiveDe ployerHook.deploy(ArchiveDeployerHook.java:76)
at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.deployer.AbstractW ebServiceDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractWebServic eDeployer.java:60)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractR ealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrap per.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: isErrors
at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.<init>(PropertyDescr iptor.java:89)
at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.<init>(PropertyDescr iptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.FaultMetaData.initializ eFaultBean(FaultMetaData.java:271)
```

It say " Method not found: isErrors" inspite of the fact that errors is not a boolean.

Can you please provide some insight into this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem.. This is the java doc for SimpleJaxwsServiceExporter.
"Note that this exporter will only work if the JAX-WS runtime actually
supports publishing with an address argument, i.e. if the JAX-WS runtime
ships an internal HTTP server. This is the case with the JAX-WS runtime
that's inclued in Sun's JDK 1.6 but not with the standalone JAX-WS 2.1 RI."

So a SimpleJaxwsServiceExporter web service implementation using spring will work on Tomcat but not on JBoss as JBoss has it own implementation of JAX-WS.

So I deployed a pure Jax-ws web service without spring support and that worked.